# Post запрос на сервер и выгрузка с него данных через json

Tags: java, android, json

Как сделать запрос изображений с удаленного ресурса и отобразить из в ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть технология [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

для отправки POST данных используется код

```
@POST("/users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

и сам парсит `Json` с помошью `gson`

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: можно `API_KEY` сделать как поле класса и передать данные